# What is the correct role for a tab container when only the currently active tab is included in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, accessibility

According to the [WAI guidelines for tabs](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/tabpanel/), one should set the role `tabpanel` on each element that contains tabbed content and then set its triggering tab's `aria-controls` value to the container's ID.

This would work well in a situation where all tabs are included in the DOM and only hidden using CSS.
However, in my application I am only adding the currently selected tab's content to the DOM using JavaScript. This means that there will only be a single `tabpanel` in the DOM and all other tabs would have `aria-controls` values set to non existing IDs, which I doubt would be good practice.

So now I'm wondering: Should I set the tabpanel role at all or should I rather just set `aria-controls` from the tabs on the container that will end up displaying whatever tab is currently selected while adding `aria-live="polite"` and `aria-relevant="all"` to it or is there a better practice for this situation?

Comment: I’m wondering why you cannot include the container with its ID already and simply add its contents to the DOM, not the container itself? Are you retrieving the contents via Fetch?

Comment: including the containers in an empty state was an idea I had as well. The contents are rendered conditionally using React with an if..else if.. etc, so having the containers there already would cause more comparison operations to be run on every render. Those operations are computationally not expensive though so not doing it this way might be premature optimization @Andy

Comment: I believe the title of the question doesn’t fit the question, which is exclusively about the `aria-controls` attribute. What do you think?

Comment: well, the question is also about where (if anywhere at all) to place the tabpanel role, not just about aria-controls

Answer (score 1):

It‘s ok to omit the `aria-control` attribute, and the tablist shoupd be placed right before the tabpanels.

### Conformance

From the [ARIA specification on role tabpanel](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#tabpanel):

> Authors SHOULD associate a tabpanel element with its tab, either by using the aria-controls attribute on the tab to reference the tab panel, or by using the aria-labelledby attribute on the tab panel to reference the tab.

So you can skip the `aria-controls` part and still be compliant.

### Practical Implications

Since most screen readers don’t make anything of `aria-controls` right now, the best practice became simply keeping `tablist` and `tabpanel` closely together, with no contents in between.

Also from the specification:

> tablist elements are typically placed near, usually preceding, a series of tabpanel elements. See the WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices for details on implementing a tab set design pattern.

This way users know to simply continue reading after changing tab, and to go back up from a tab panel to change tab. In most articles I read, this is highly recommended.

Of course we should not skip indicating semantics just because implementation is not there yet (e.g. as most developers did with `inputmode`). But if it poses an issue in your case, you can omit the `aria-controls` attribute.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not most screen readers make anything of `aria-controls`, it's somewhat supported by JAWS, which has a larger user-base than any other. I'd disagree with the sentiment that it makes sense to just fully omit `aria-controls` just because it's not supported everywhere. Including it provides additional support for some users and doesn't cost anything. https://a11ysupport.io/tests/tech__aria__aria-controls

Comment: "Aria-Controls is Poop" - https://heydonworks.com/article/aria-controls-is-poop/.  Granted, the article is 6 years old but is still somewhat valid.  It talks about JAWS and coincides with what @Josh says about it **somewhat** supporting it. Nobody else supports it  It dosn't really gain you much by using it. Semantically, it's correct and I usually side with good semantics but I like to balance that with not writing code that doesn't add any value.

Comment: I rephrased the justification to be less encouraging (;